# Need Help for HTACCESS PHP ID rewriterule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite

```
www.domain.com/xyzdetails.php?id=91741
```

to

```
www.domain.com/rakesh-gupta
```

`rakesh-gupta` is saved as `rakesh gupta` in the table as field `title` for php id `91741`.

I tried method using below url, but didn't work out.

http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `didn't work out`? Did it error? What code did you use?

Comment: https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: I think you are trying to make your URL too friendly. If I'm not mistaken, you will have to hard code every single row of your table as a rewrite rule because the rewrite engine doesn't know in advance the `title` for a specific `id` and has no means of accessing it unless hard coding. Normally you would settle with rewriting `www.domain.com/details/91741` to something like `www.domain.com/xyzdetails.php?id=91741`. Sure that is not what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rewrite by any static string like `rakesh-gupta/12345` then the rule can be

```
# www.domain.com/rakesh-gupta/12345
RewriteRule ^rakesh-gupta/(\d+)$
```

And if you think your rewrite URL will be dynamic instead then the *regex* can be written as `^(.*)/(\d+)$`. Here first group `(.*)` is anything (title, name, business, .....) and second group `\d+` is for id and the rule is

```
# www.domain.com/rakesh-gupta/12345
# www.domain.com/title/12345
# www.domain.com/...../12345
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\d+)$ /xyzdetails.php?id=$2
```

Hope it will make you sense.

Comment: Hi, Got a Q, rakesh gupta is just one value, so for entire table do i need to create htaccess file as  RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^title/(\d+)$ /xyzdetails.php?id=$1

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\d+)$ /xyzdetails.php?id=$2`. it will work for any pattern `/any_char/id_no`

Comment: my URL is 
http://rejoicep.com/recruitment-drive-detail.php?recrid=1
and I want this to convert with:
http://rejoicep.com/Jobs-In-Andhra-Pradesh-For-ABAP-Consultant

and like this to change with every id 

http://rejoicep.com/recruitment-drive-detail.php?recrid=2

http://rejoicep.com/Jobs-In-Adilabad-For-ABAP-Consultant


I tried the below htaccess files.

Option 1

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\d+)$ /recruitment-drive-detail.php?id=$2


Option 2
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^jobtitle/(\d+)$ /recruitment-drive-detail.php?id=$1

Am I making some mistake here.